# Programación sockets multicast. InetAddress.getByName(direccionMulticast). UnknownHostException: /239.0.0.0

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplición distribuda que hace uso de las bibliotecas de sockets multicast de Java. Me salta una excepción en la siguiente línea:

```
        direccionMulticast = InetAddress.getByName( tokenizer.nextToken() );
```

La resultado de `tokenize.nextToken()` es `"239.0.0.0"`

Este el `printStackTrace` que me sale es este:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: /239.0.0.0
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
```

Lo que quiero hacer al final es crear un socket multicast que se una a un grupo. Es decir, lo que se ve en el código siguiente:

```
multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket (PUERTO_MULTICAST);
multicastSocket.joinGroup(direccionMulticast);
```

Comment: ¿cuál es la excepción?

Comment: Por favor, agrega el mensaje de error completo, incluyendo el stack trace.

Comment: IOException, es lo que capturo en el catch

Comment: @jpuriol: Haz `e.printStackTrace()` para ver los detalles del error. Es difícil diagnosticar el error si ignoras los detalles del error que te lanza la aplicación.

Comment: Ahora le añado el printStackTrace

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `tokenize.nextToken()` te devuelve `239.0.0.0`? Yo no creo. Como ya te expliqué en mi respuesta, `tokenize.nextToken()` debe estar devolviéndote `/239.0.0.0`.  ¿Qué sucede si ejecutas esta sentencia: `InetAddress.getByName( "239.0.0.0" );`... ¿te lanza un error? ¿Verdad que no? ¿Y que pasa si intentas: `InetAddress.getByName( "/239.0.0.0" );`?

Comment: @sstan tienes razón. Voy a ver si consigo arreglarlo. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: /239.0.0.0
```

tienes un `/` en frente del IP address que no debería estar allí. De modo que, aparentemente, el problema reside en la manera como divides tu cadena en tokens.

De paso, la línea que te lanza la excepción es la siguiente (lo puedes ver en el stack trace):

```
direccionMulticast = InetAddress.getByName( tokenizer.nextToken() );
```

Como ves, es buena idea de no ignorar los detalles de la excepción que te lanza la aplicación para poder corregir este tipo de defecto.

Comment: Gracias por identificar el error, voy a reformular la pregunta a ver si se ver si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar el error.

Comment: Acabo de refomular la pregunta de forma que se ve más claro mi problema. Gracias por ayudarme.